# Как прочитать данные из файла в Objective-C?

Tags: xcode, файлы, macos, objective-c

Файл *Graf.txt* содержить пару чисел в каждой строки. Необходимо вывести содержимое файла. На *С++* я это делаю так:

```
ifstream input("Graf.txt");
int i, j;
while(!input.eof())
        input >> i >> j;
        cout >> i >> j >> endl;
```

А как реализовать это на Objective-C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто:

**UPD:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString* filePath = @"Graf.txt";
        NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSLog(@"File body: %@", myText);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое "бандл". Как его туда добавить?

Comment: Разрабатываю под OS X.

Comment: У меня ничего не выводит. Может путь к Graf.txt как-то нужно указать? Где должен лежать файл, чтобы приложение его видело?

Comment: Да естественно, но можете попробывать указать прямой путь, а не относительный. А так посмотите куда билдится проджект.

Comment: Указал прямой путь: NSString* filePath = @"/Users/DerKode/Documents/Code/GrafObjc/Graf.txt" и заработало. 
А как узнать куда билдиться проект? Я привык в Windows к ".exe" и плохо ориентируюсь в Mac OS.

Comment: АаааааРРрррр Все же заставили меня запустить этот Xcode! 
File -> Project Settings ->Advanced...
Там посмотрите.